# Prove that series with $n$-th term $(-1)^n\cdot\frac{n^{n}}{(n+1)^{n+1}}$ is convergent

Tags: calculus

Trying to apply Alternating Series Test to prove the convergence of series above, which boils down to proving that:
$n^{n}(n+2)^{n+2}>(n+1)^{2*(n+1)}$
which could be easily verified for any number of values of $n$ starting from $1$ upwards, but at the moment I don't see how to prove it in general.

Comment: Don't use double dollar sign in the title, and make yourself clear: is it $(-1)$ to that messy power or $\,(-1)^n\,$ *times* that fractional expression?

Comment: It's $(-1)^n$ times the fractional expression indeed; I've put \cdot in the title, hope this helps in disambiguating it. As for double dollar sign, haven't put these there...

Comment: [$ (n/n+1)^n$ and $1/(n+1)$ are both decreasing hence their product is decreasing too..]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Use standard devices from the calculus to study the behaviour of $\dfrac{x^x}{(x+1)^{x+1}}$, by studying the behaviour of its logarithm.

Comment: Got it: so the derivative of $$\log\frac{x^{x}}{(x+1)^{x+1}}$$ is $$\log x-\log(x+1)$$ thus always negative, which means this function is decreasing, which further means $\frac{x^{x}}{(x+1)^{x+1}}$ function is decreasing too, thus given alternating series is convergent.  Thanks.

Comment: You are welcome. There are more basic no calculus ways to do it, but might as well hit it with a hammer.

Answer (score 1):

Well , it is conditionally  convergent.

To show conditional convergence ,note that the nth term decreases monotonically to $0$ in the limit.

[$ (n/n+1)^n$ and $1/(n+1)$ are both decreasing hence their product is decreasing too..]

For absolute convergence , use comparison test with the harmonic series and conclude that it

isn't absolutely convergent.You also need the fact that $\lim_{n \to\infty }  (1+1/n)^n=e$.

Comment: I fixed it..thank you..